# How can I find the Xpath of a HTML tag's title attribute and print the text of said title

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using pythons scrapy library. I want to be able to scrape the text contained within the `<h1>`'s `title` attribute from the following html code using Xpath selectors.

```
<h1>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.cpm/" title="Go to Facebook home">
    <i class="fb_logo img sp_z3EmYTfbUvU_1_5x sx_91465b">...</i>
   </a>
</h1>
```

This is what I tried already, but it does not work. How can this be made to work?

```
response.xpath('//h1/a/title()').extract()
```

The data I require is as follows:

```
"Go to Facebook home"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you are using wrong `xpath` to extract the attribute `title`

Use as:

```
response.xpath('//h1/a/@title').extract()    #i just change /title() to @title
```

Comment: I want to know how to decide what to write in xpath for eg: you changed (/title() to @title() ).   why did you changed "/" with "@". Is there some concept behind it ?? what shoud  i study to get this concept?

Comment: `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp` here you can find the syntax of `xpath`

Comment: how can i extract the url of the webpage??

Comment: `current_url = response.url` and please post new questions as new rather than asking in comment section :)

Answer (score 2):

When using selectors in scrapy you should import scrapy's `Selector` first, like so:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
```

The correct way to use xpath in scrapy now is to utilize the `Selector` class, like so:

```
response = '''<h1>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.cpm/" title="Go to Facebook home">
    <i class="fb_logo img sp_z3EmYTfbUvU_1_5x sx_91465b">...</i>
   </a>
</h1>'''

title = Selector(text=response).xpath('//h1/a/@title').extract()
```

This will return a list object:

```
['Go to Facebook home']
```

Now you can get your text as a string by using a list index:

```
title[0]
```

I highly recommend reading the [scrapy docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/) especially on [selectors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) and even learn [about xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) too.